# how to get data from such array

Tags: php, arrays

```
object(stdClass)#3 (12) { 
  ["responseCode"]=> string(4) "0000" 
  ["orderId"]=> string(6) "456456" 
  ["storeId"]=> int(5591) 
  ["storeName"]=> string(26) "rr bb" 
  ["paymentToken"]=> string(7) "1784388" 
  ["transactionId"]=> string(6) "6456456" 
  ["transactionStatus"]=> string(7) "PENDING" 
  ["transactionAmount"]=> float(6945) 
  ["transactionDateTime"]=> string(29) "2018-07-31T12:46:46.000+05:00" 
  ["paymentTokenExiryDateTime"]=> string(29) "2018-08-04T12:46:46.393+05:00" 
  ["msisdn"]=> string(11) "0345555" 
  ["paymentMode"]=> string(3) "OTC" 
}
```

I have a `Soap API` function and a variable I receive above data using `print_r` command

Now I want a signal data `paymentToken` how to access this in `PHP` :

```
<?php echo  $var1->paymentToken; ?>
<?php echo  $var1['paymentToken']; ?>
```

Comment: just access the object properties like you normally would do

Comment: i am using this to get single data <?php echo  $var1->paymentToken; ?><?php echo  $var1['paymentToken']; ?>

Comment: What is wrong if you access it using `$var1->paymentToken` as in your example code?

Comment: then it show nothing

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
$OpenAPI = new OpenAPI; 
$var = $OpenAPI->inquireTransaction();
echo $var->paymentToken;
```

Here $object should have above given data.

Comment: look i am using this $OpenAPI = new OpenAPI;
 $var = $OpenAPI->inquireTransaction(); when i print_r($var) then the whole data is shown but to access one i am using   <?php echo  $var -> transactionAmount; ?>

Comment: Answer Updated!

Answer (score 0):

You can access a public accessible attribute in a stdClass like this:

```
$object->attribute;
```

You can access a value in array like this:

```
$object['attribute'];
```

(You also can cast the stdClass into an array like this:)

```
$attribute = (array)$myStdClass['attribute'];
```

Comment: unable to get the data

Comment: i am using this $OpenAPI = new OpenAPI; 
$var = $OpenAPI->inquireTransaction();
echo $var->paymentToken;

Comment: Maybe you should have added it to your question that you're using OpenAPI. Don't know this framework.